# How to get 4 sequetial numbers for postcode in javascript from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, postal-code

I am trying to figure out how to get 4 sequential numbers from a string which will be a postcode from the string. [The regex seems to work fine in regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/59MCvj/1) but when I try to use it in javascript I get an error that reads `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?`

My code is

```
var str = "1 George Road, Sydney  NSW 2000"; 
console.log(str.match(((?<!\d)(\d{4}(\d{4})?)\b)));
```

Comment: besides your lack of `//` ... you have `pcre (php)` checked on regex 101 - so, that won't help checking javascript regexp - and JS regexp doesn't "support" negative lookbehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must  include `//g`  on regex for example `/Your Pattern/g`

```js
var str = "1 George Road, Sydney  NSW 2000"; 
console.log(str.match(/((?<!\d)(\d{4}(\d{4})?)\b)/g));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why jquery? and why the global flag? Did you check? Did you notice the error? `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group`

Comment: Thanks a lot Shree, that fixed it. Didnt notice I misssed the `//g`

Comment: oh ... seems Chrome does support negative lookbehind - spot the chrome users

Comment: that's great ... half the internet doesn't ... so if your web page is public facing, do take into account the increasing number of people not using Chrum